# Cannot get view to work on SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a view that includes columns froms several tables.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

And this is my query:

```
SELECT     
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.WebPortalBillingId, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.CorporationId, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.TokenId, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.GatewaySupportFee, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.GatewayPerTransactionFee, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.PortalPerCustomerFee, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.PortalSupportFee, 
   Customer.Account.AccountNumber, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.IsActive, 
   Customer.Customer.Name, 
   Customer.Customer.TaxCode, 
   Company.CorporationStructure.Branch
FROM         
   Company.CorporationStructure 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   Customer.Account ON Company.CorporationStructure.CorporationStructureId = Customer.Account.CorporationStructureId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   Customer.Customer ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Customer.Branch 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   Billing.WebPortalBilling ON Customer.Account.CorporationId = Billing.WebPortalBilling.CorporationId
WHERE     
   (Billing.WebPortalBilling.IsActive = 1)
```

It's only returning 1 record, which is not correct. I'm trying to tie the Customer's name back to the WebPortalBilling table along with the account number and branth in the other two tables.

I'm new to sql, so be kind.

Thanks!

Comment: Is you left or right join on webportalbilling, but then require a specific value in a webportalbilling column, then it makes it essentially an inner join.  Take out the where and see what you get.  Or include null as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented the where is killing the outer
Try

```
SELECT     
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.WebPortalBillingId, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.CorporationId, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.TokenId, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.GatewaySupportFee, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.GatewayPerTransactionFee, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.PortalPerCustomerFee, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.PortalSupportFee, 
   Customer.Account.AccountNumber, 
   Billing.WebPortalBilling.IsActive, 
   Customer.Customer.Name, 
   Customer.Customer.TaxCode, 
   Company.CorporationStructure.Branch
FROM         
   Company.CorporationStructure 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   Customer.Account ON Company.CorporationStructure.CorporationStructureId = Customer.Account.CorporationStructureId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   Customer.Customer ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Customer.Branch 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN  Billing.WebPortalBilling 
    ON Customer.Account.CorporationId = Billing.WebPortalBilling.CorporationId
   AND Billing.WebPortalBilling.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: gotcha... I get it now tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think left joins are clearer.

```
SELECT    
  B.WebPortalBillingId, 
  B.CorporationId,   
  B.TokenId, 
  B.GatewaySupportFee, 
  B.GatewayPerTransactionFee, 
  B.PortalPerCustomerFee, 
  B.PortalSupportFee, 
  C.AccountNumber, 
  B.IsActive, 
  C.Name,
  C.TaxCode, 
  CS.Branch
FROM  Customer.Customer C
  LEFT JOIN  Company.CorporationStructure CS ON CS.Branch = C.Branch 
  LEFT JOIN  Customer.Account A ON CS.CorporationStructureId = A.CorporationStructureId
  LEFT JOIN  Billing.WebPortalBilling B ON A.CorporationId = B.CorporationId
WHERE B.IsActive = 1
```